# Работа с базой данных в C# добавление в базу данных из TextBox

Tags: c#

Как через `textbox` можно добавить данные в базу данных. Например есть кнопка `Добавить`. Нажимаешь и оно добавляется `DbGrid`, а затем нажимаем на кнопку `Сохранить` и оно добавляется в  базу данных, ну или можно что бы сразу сохранялась в базе данных...... Да, и если можно что это не было `DataSet`
или `Entity`, или `Linq to Sql`, или `linq to Entity`.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор просит проделать работу за него. Такие задачи уместны на сайте фрилансеров, но не на StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ildarik07 напишите, что Вы уже сделали, а мы поможем найти ошибки если что...

Comment: мне не нужен код! мне нужна суть как  можно проделать это! какие команды или в какую сторону хотя бы нужно копать! я не понимаю как можно в базу данных сохранять из textbox и вообще реально ли такое или нужно сначала нужно внести все в dataGrid  а потом обновить базу!  И все! я же не прошу написать за меня код! А то что тема не соответствует это не суть совсем...если ответ знаете пишем если нет то Бог с ним в другом месте поищем...

Answer (score 1):

Можете создать `SqlConnection` и передать параметр в команду.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Update:**
В обработчике нажатия на кнопку берете значение textbox и пишете в базу используя SqlConnection/SqlCommand/SqlParameter
Вот пример из
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlclient

```
static void AddDog(int weight, string name, string breed)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    ConsoleApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.masterConnectionString))
    {
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Dogs1 VALUES(@Weight, @Name, @Breed)", con))
        {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Weight", weight));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", name));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Breed", breed));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Count not insert.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность ).